# How do I import the MaxEnt (Java) outputs from my models into R for AIC calculation?

Tags: java, r, model, maxent

I ran a few models in the Java MaxEnt program showing the species distribution model of an invasive species, and I want to import the outputs that it gave me (I have a folder of them, some asc files, some html, some plot pngs…) into R in order to compare the fit of each model via AIC. How do I go about doing this?

I want to use this code:

aic.maxent(p.occs, ncoefs, p = NULL)

Comment: This looks promising: https://github.com/johnbaums/rmaxent

Comment: Welcome to SO! To get better feedback, you may want to share some example data so others can dig in and play: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example